# What is the meaning of the expression "I can see where you're coming from"?

Tags: idioms

When I heard,

> ***"I can see where you're coming from?"***

in the first time, I thought that they were saying something about my place of origin.

But now I think it means,

> ***"I can understand your point of view."***

Is it the meaning of this American expression?

Comment: Googled "I can see where you're coming from" and clicked on the second link: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-see-where-sb-is-coming-from

Comment: Metaphorically, your *point of view* is governed by your *where you are, your vantage point*, so you might find it easier to grasp the idiom by considering, say, *I understand your **position** [on the subject under discussion]* (i.e. *how you relate to it, spatially / figuratively*). It's quite natural to say *I approach this question from the position of a native speaker* (i.e. - that's where I'm "coming from"). Note that there's also *I can see **where you're going** with this*, which is often effectively equivalent.

Comment: ...and *I don't support **his line** on this* (i.e. - the *direction* of his argument).

Answer (score 1):

If you see where a person is coming from, you understand why a person has a particular point of view even though you do not share it.